# How to make custom overlay div resizeable

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is my code. when i upload image then image show css dots for resize Div but it does not resize div. please give the solution.

```
function loadMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), {
    center: { lat: centerCoordinate.lat, lng: centerCoordinate.lng },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
if (cemeteryImage != null) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
       new google.maps.LatLng(centerCoordinate.lat, centerCoordinate.lng),
       new google.maps.LatLng(centerCoordinate.lat + 0.118652, centerCoordinate.lng + 0.281524));
    var srcImage = '/images/CemeteryPlots/' + cemeteryImage;
    overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
    var offsetX = 0.40;
    var offsetY = 0.40;
    var span = map.getBounds().toSpan();
    var newCenter = {
        lat: centerCoordinate.lat + span.lat() * offsetY,
        lng: centerCoordinate.lng + span.lng() * offsetX
    };
    map.panTo(newCenter);
}
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    draggable: true,
    position: centerCoordinate,
    icon: '/images/icon/re-position.png'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function (event) {
    var latt = this.getPosition().lat();
    var lngg = this.getPosition().lng();
    centerCoordinate.lat = latt;
    centerCoordinate.lng = lngg;
    if (cemeteryImage != null) {
        overlay.setMap(null);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
           new google.maps.LatLng(latt, lngg),
           new google.maps.LatLng(latt + 0.118652, lngg + 0.281524));
        var srcImage = '/images/CemeteryPlots/' + cemeteryImage;
        overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
    }
});



// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

// Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
});
zoom = map.getZoom();
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
    zoom = map.getZoom();
});
var markers = [];
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
// more details for that place.
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    //var latitude = places[0].geometry.location.latitude;
    //var longitude = places[0].geometry.location.longitude;
    $("#txtLatitude").val(places[0].geometry.location.lat());
    $("#txtLongitude").val(places[0].geometry.location.lng());
    $("#txtAddress").val(places[0].formatted_address);
    centerCoordinate.lat = places[0].geometry.location.lat();
    centerCoordinate.lng = places[0].geometry.location.lng();
    if (cemeteryImage != null) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
           new google.maps.LatLng(centerCoordinate.lat, centerCoordinate.lng),
           new google.maps.LatLng(centerCoordinate.lat + 0.118652, centerCoordinate.lng + 0.281524));
        var srcImage = '/images/CemeteryPlots/' + cemeteryImage;
        overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
        var offsetX = 0.40;
        var offsetY = 0.40;
        var span = map.getBounds().toSpan();
        var newCenter = {
            lat: centerCoordinate.lat + span.lat() * offsetY,
            lng: centerCoordinate.lng + span.lng() * offsetX
        };
        map.panTo(newCenter);
    }

    if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

     //Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function (place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }
        var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        // Create a marker for each place.
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            //icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            draggable: true,
           // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: centerCoordinate
       });
       markers.push(marker);
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function (e) {
           var lat, lng, address;
           geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
               if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                   lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                   lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
                   $("#txtLatitude").val(lat);
                   $("#txtLongitude").val(lng);

                   //address = results[0].formatted_address;
                   //$("#txtLatitude").val(lat);
                   //$("#txtLongitude").val(lng);
                   //$("#txtMapAddress").val(address);
                   //$("#divWholeForm").slideDown();
                   //alert("Latitude: " + lat + "\nLongitude: " + lng + "\nAddress: " + address);
               }
           });
       });




        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});

}

var overlay;
var USGSOverlay = function (bounds, image, map) {
this.bounds_ = bounds;
this.image_ = image;
this.map_ = map;
this.div_ = null;
this.setMap(map);
}
var loadMapWithImage = function () {
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.resize = 'both';
    div.style.overflow = 'auto';
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image_;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    //img.style.opacity = '0.5'
    div.appendChild(img);
    this.div_ = div;
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
};
loadMap();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ry47.png)
please give me the solution for resizing custom overlay div

Comment: What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Try viewing your page in chrome and see if you have the same problem